# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4] '

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsrangeexception

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    SimpleeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.TitleLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.PlaceLabel.text = [placeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.RankingsLabel.text = [rankingsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.StatusLabel.text = [statusData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.DistanceLabel.text = [distanceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash? Where do you says how many rows in the corresponding delegate method?

Comment: Yeah which one of the 6 arrays that make up your dataset is causing the issue?

Answer (score -1):

your `tableData` or `placeData` or `XXXdata` 's count is less than your cell's count.
you can make some breakpoint in these line.

    `cell.TitleLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.PlaceLabel.text = [placeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.RankingsLabel.text = [rankingsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.StatusLabel.text = [statusData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.DistanceLabel.text = [distanceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

you can also use `tableData.count` to see if it's out of range.

Comment: @amuthakumari one or more than one of your `tableData` `placeData`  `rankingsData` `statusData` and `distanceData` don't  have enough object. This error is often  come up with `objectAtIndex:` when the `index`parameter is beyond the array's count. For example ,you have an array with `array=@[0,1,2,3]`,which has 4 object ,and you call method like this `array objectAtIndex:5`.